# Having issue converting dataframe to json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import json

csv_file = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False)
print(csv_file.head())

csv_file.to_json("file.json", orient = "records", date_format = "epoch", double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
```

How do I convert my dataframe to json file? It gives extra forward slashes in URLs such as : `https:\/\/covers.openlibrary.org\/w\/id\/7984916-M.jpg`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Escaped forward slashes are legitimate JSON.  The spec allows for this.  The JSON recipient, when loading the JSON data, will decode it properly.  This can be shown in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""index,url
1,https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7984916-M.jpg
""")

csv_df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False)
print(csv_df.head())

jsondata = StringIO()
csv_df.to_json(jsondata, orient = "records", date_format = "epoch", double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)

json_str = jsondata.getvalue()
print(json_str)
a_dict = json.loads(json_str)
print(a_dict)
```

Which produces

```
0.24.2
   index                                                url
0      1  https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7984916-M.jpg
[{"index":1,"url":"https:\/\/covers.openlibrary.org\/w\/id\/7984916-M.jpg"}]
[{'index': 1, 'url': 'https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7984916-M.jpg'}]
```